# facebook comment plugin asp.net

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-comments

i want to include facebook comment box in facebook application built in asp.net
i have already tried facebook comment plugin but somehow it does not work and gives all.jss errors can anyone suggest working sample
for example my current one looks like.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <%--  <script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"
        type="text/javascript" />--%>
    <%--    <script type="text/javascript">
        FB.init("163659850382295", "xdreciever.htm");
    </script>--%>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://aspspider.ws/prashantkurlekar/likeTest.aspx"
        data-num-posts="10" data-width="500">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What JavaScript error messages are you receiving?

Comment: i recieve script error all.js thats all in ie bottom right !Error on page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [original Comments box](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/198/), which has been replaced by a newer version. I would view the [current documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) and see if the errors disappear.